# Scala dynamic repository

Tags: scala

i'm pretty new to scala. I've tried to create a kind of dynamic repository. How can i read the attributes of a simple case class?

```
trait Repository[T <:MetaEntity] {

    persist(entity:T) : Boolean {
        // TO BE IMPLEMENTED

        // Pseudo code:
        for (attribute <- getAttributes()) {
           // Flatten properies to one string...
           // Primitives can be converted with attribute.value.toString ?
           // Type: attribute.type ?
           // Object references should be coverted to object.id.toString ?
        } 
    }   

}

abstarct class MetaEntity {}

case class SimpleEntity(id: Int, name: String, version: Int) extends MetaEntity {
}

case class ComplexEntity(id: Int, name: String, simpleChild: SimpleEntity) extends MetaEntity{}

object ComplexEntityRepository extends Repository[ComplexEntity] {}
object SimpleEntityRepository extends Repository[SimpleEntity] {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just represent your entities as maps? You could then easily iterate over the keys as attributes and do all the other fancy stuff that Scala maps can do.

If you want to hide the representation, then you should use composition, i.e. store the map as a private field.

Something like this could get you started:

```
class Entity {
  private[this] val map = collection.mutable.Map[String, Any]()
  def name = map("name").asInstanceOf[String]
  def attributes = map.keys
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems to be the straight forward way. Is it possible to create something like that: class MyEntity extends Entity { object name extends NameField(owner = this) } (I've seen similar code on the net but don't get it how it works at all) ?

Comment: I've updated my sample to show how this could work for a virtual field 'name'.

Comment: I don't know your use case. May be you should simply use normal classes and persist to XML or JSON. There are some good articles on the web for that. Explaining it here would be too long.

Answer (score 1):

Case classes in scala extend Product (see [here](http://dcsobral.blogspot.de/2009/06/case-classes-and-product.html)).
Maybe the following code will help you (REPL session):

```
scala> trait MetaEntity extends Product
defined trait MetaEntity

scala> case class Test(i: Int, j: Int) extends MetaEntity
defined class Test

scala> def test[T <: MetaEntity](t: T) = {
     |   for (elem <- t.productIterator)
     |     println(elem.getClass.getName + " " + elem)
     | }
test: [T <: MetaEntity](t: T)Unit

scala> test(Test(1,2))

java.lang.Integer 1
java.lang.Integer 2
```

To read the attributes of "inner" products you can do type checking (e.g. iter.next.isInstanceOf[Product]).